# What creates a remote git repository?

Tags: git

I am using a server to hold the remote backup of my code using git. I ran the command, `git remote add laptop_remote //sysopt/GitRepo/Laptop_Workspace` and when I run `git remote -v`, I see the remote appears to be setup:

```
laptop_remote   //sysopt/GitRepo/Laptop_Workspace (fetch)
laptop_remote   //sysopt/GitRepo/Laptop_Workspace (push)
origin  //sysopt/GitRepo/Workspace (fetch)
origin  //sysopt/GitRepo/Workspace (push)
```

However, when I run `git push -u laptop_remote --all`, I get the following response:

```
fatal: '//sysopt/GitRepo/Laptop_Workspace' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Sure enough, on the server there is no Laptop_Workspace directory so...what creates it?
FWIW, I have tried manually creating to no avail.

Comment: A remote is another git repo. You can create one using `git init`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git remote` command just sets up, in your local repository's config, a "pointer" to where a remote repository should be.

The result of your `push` indicates that there is not actually a repository in the location you indicated.

If you have access to the remote location you can create a repo there by going to the intended location and using `git init --bare` .

Comment: I added the directory as 'Laptop_Workspace.git' then did `cd Laptop_Workspace.git` followed by `git init --bare`. Now when I go back to my laptop's workspace directory and run `git push -u laptop_remote --all` it works as expected. Thank-you !